# How do I deal with timestamp in bosun configuration?

Tags: elasticsearch, bosun

I'm trying to insert an alert in elasticsearch from bosun but I don't know how to fill the variable `$timestamp` (Have a look at my example) with the present time. Can I use functions in `bosun.conf`? I'd like something like `now()`.
Can anybody help me, please?

This is an extract of an example configuration:

```
macro m1
{
    $timestamp = **???**
}
notification http_crit
{
    macro = m1
    post =  http://xxxxxxx:9200/alerts/http/
    body = {"@timestamp":$timestamp,"level":"critical","alert_name":"my_alert"}
    next = http_crit
    timeout = 1m
}
alert http
{
    template = elastic
    $testHTTP = lscount("logstash", "", "_type:stat_http,http_response:200", "1m", "5m", "")
    $testAvgHTTP  = avg($testHTTP)
    crit = $testAvgHTTP < 100
    critNotification = http_crit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We use `.State.Touched.Format` which was recently renamed to `.Last.Time.Format` in the master branch. The format string is a [go time format](https://golang.org/pkg/time/), and you would have to get it to print the correct format that elastic is expecting.

```
template elastic {
    subject = `Time: {{.State.Touched.Format "15:04:05UTC"}}`
}
//Changed on 2016 Feb 01 to
template elastic {
    subject = `Time: {{.Last.Time.Format "15:04:05UTC"}}`
}
```

Which when rendered would look like:

> Time: 01:30:13UTC

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is perfect for the template but I can't use this in a macro or in the notification, can I ?